# Unable to create new folder. (ctrl+shift+N) is not working in my HDD partitions folder

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, mount, hard-drive

I have Windows10 in my HP laptop. Also I have 500GB HDD. I partition this HDD in windows10 and make three 100GB partition , all are in NTFS . Then two days before I install Ubuntu 18.04 LTS in my laptop. This partions are seen by clicking in other locations tab in ubuntu , it is shown as **/dev/sda5**, **/dev/sda6** and **/dev/sda7** . Yesterday I successfully create folder on /dev/sda5 by right click . But today I am unable to create new folder ( either by right-click or by ctrl+shift+N ) . What can I do ?

Comment: Yesterday I create a folder **Main** in \dev\sda5 . I enter into "Main" folder, there also unable to create new folder . Also select any document inside the "Main" folder, right-click on it , then I see that **cut**, **Move to** and **Rename** options are inactive. Why this happens ?

Comment: You can just do `mkdir "name of the folder"` simply to create one

Comment: @Tintin I want to create folder of name 'abc' bu using "mkdir abc" in terminal , but this will give the following message : "mkdir: cannot create directory ‘abc’: Read-only file system"

Comment: So you see that's the major problem which you should've mentioned in the post itself

Comment: @user68186 Yes problem is solved , thank you so much .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is caused by Windows 10 default fast Startup setting.

## Boot Windows

Turn off Fast Startup in Systems Settings:

1. Open the Control Panel (icons view), and click on the **Power Options** icon.
2. Click on the Choose what the power buttons do link on the left side. (see screenshot below)

[image]

3. Click on the **Change settings that are currently unavailable** link at the top. (see screenshot below)

[image]

4. Under Shutdown settings, uncheck the Turn on fast startup box, click on the Save changes button. (see screenshot below)

[image]

Source: [TenForums](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/4189-turn-off-fast-startup-windows-10-a.html)

## Boot Ubuntu

The new partitions should now work as expected.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

In a dual boot system, from ubunut itself you can try these two commands to fix the **read only error** and the associated error of ' **cannot create directory ‘path/to/dir’: No such file or directory**'

First try remounting the partition(say /dev/sdb2) with write options using the command

```
sudo mount -o remount,rw /dev/sdb2
```

If it shows error 'No such file or directory' when you try to cretae new directory, then run ntfsfix followed by remount command(assuming this is the same ntfs partition used in windows)

```
sudo ntfsfix /dev/sdb2
sudo mount -o remount,rw /dev/sdb2
```